# Absolute and Relative Imports - Importing module in subfolder2 from subfolder1

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

### Project Structure

I have the following project structure:

```
pythonProject\
    modules\
        __init__.py
        module1\
            __init__.py
            script1.py
        module2\
            __init__.py
            script2.py
```

the content of script2.py is:

```
def script2_function():
  return "Import worked successfully"
```

---

### **Absolute Import**

When trying an absolute import, the content of script1.py is:

```
from modules.module2.script2 import script2_function

print(script2_function())
```

When running script1.py (both from the project root and the module1 directory) I get the following error:

*****ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modules'*****

---

### **Relative Import**

When trying an absolute import, the content of script1.py is:

```
from ..module2.script2 import script2_function

print(script2_function())
```

When running script1.py (both from the project root and the module1 directory) I get the following error:

*****ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package*****

---

I honestly cannot understand what I am doing wrong, and tried following several guides and stack answers, but nothing has solved this issue.
Can you please explain me how to solve it, so I can better understand both relative and absolute python imports?

Thank you in advance for any help provided.

Comment: The main script (with which the program is started) should be in the "highest" place (in "pythonProject" directly). Modules below it and in the same directory can then be imported (also by each other in the shown way).

Comment: @MichaelButscher Is there no other way to run script1.py directly, without having a"main script" in the project root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly you could either change directory to the `pythonProject` directory and run `python3 -m modules.module1.script1`.  The `import` statement is relative to where you are running Python from.

The other option of course would be to have `script1.py` in the project root which is similar to the above and for many projects may make more sense.

For both of the above the import statement in `script1.py` can either be `from modules.module2.script2 import script2_function` or `from ..module2.script2 import script2_function`.

Apologies if I have misunderstood the question.

Comment: Thank you very much Matt. That was indeed the problem with the absolute imports!
Do you know how to make it work with relative imports?

Comment: I've just checked and the solution in the first paragraph will work for relative imports too (I don't tend to use relative imports in my own work so was not sure, but now I have learned something!) :)

I will edit my answer.